# How to play MediaPlayer once in onLocationChanged in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-mediaplayer

I'm already made a mechanism that detects a position in maps and calculate its distance from the user (in meters).

I want to play a raw audio file if that position is in desire distance (in my case in 30 meters).

I already made this code in my onLocationChanged()

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
          float dis = calcdist(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude,lat,lng);
          if(dis <= 30) {
             MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sound);
             mp.setLooping(false);
             mp.start();
          } else {
             mp.stop();
          }
       } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
  }
```

Now the problem is, whenever the user get move, its fire up that function again and play the sound over and over until the distance is more than 30 meter.

I know why it happening exactly but I can't find the right way to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
          int a = 0;
          float dis = calcdist(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude,lat,lng);
          if(dis <= 30) {

             int a = a+1; //add 1 if you are in the circle

             if(a = 1) { //if a=1 it will do the rest
                     MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.sound);
                     mp.setLooping(false);
                     mp.start();
                 } else {
                     mp.stop();
                 }
           }

           //if you are not int he circle

           if(dis > 30) {
               int a = 0;
           }

       } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
  }
```

What about this? It will just set if you are already in circle of that 30 meters. If yes it will let you play that audio, if not it wont do anything. I am sorry for my english and hope I helped you.